# How to get the objectname of array with Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I guess this is relativly easy, but I just can't figure out how to do this.

**part of the HTML/JS (Jquery) file**

```
  var checkedBox = $('input[name=ProductType]:checked').val();

            $.getJSON('getdata.php', {ProductType: checkedBox}, function(getit) {
                $.each(getit, function(index, array) {
```

After fetching a variable array thru JSON from a PHP file. I can see the following information in the console:

**Console**

```
[{"color":"red"},{"color":"blue"},{"color":"yellow"}]
```

Depending on the value of the checkbox, the PHP file will return the array objectname. (In this case "color") with its corresponding values.

Now I would like to catch this array objectname in a var with Jquery or JS, because the array objectnames can differ. But how can I do this?

Comment: If they all have the same key, Why can't you just return an array of strings? `['red', 'blue', 'yellow']`

Comment: Because I would like to use the key to output the data to several div id's in a different part of my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you want to do is to extract the name from the JSON data.  If you have this data that comes back from your PHP JSON:

```
var getit = [{"color":"red"},{"color":"blue"},{"color":"yellow"}];
```

And, you want to get the common attribute name from that and all values in the array have the same name, you could so so like this:

```
function getKeyName(data) {
    var firstItem = data[0];  // look at first array element
    for (var i in firstItem) {
        return(i);  // return first property name found
    }
}

var attributeName = getKeyName(getit);
```

If you control the JSON data format, I would think it would be a more useful data format to have it like this:

```
{"name": "color", "values": ["red", "blue", "yellow"]}
```

Then you could directly access:

```
data.name   // "color"
data.values // ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
```